# Oracle SQL: Declaring a variable and using the variable in other queries

Tags: sql, oracle, dbeaver

I'm new to Oracle Database and I'm having some trouble with declaring variables and using that in other queries. For example, I want to create a variable called caseID with which store a number based on the select statement. Then I want to use that caseID in other queries I want to create. This is what I have:

```
DECLARE
   caseID NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT case_id FROM cases WHERE user_id = 'test';
END;

SELECT * FROM version where case_id = :caseID
MINUS
SELECT * FROM version where version_type = 'A'
```

I'm not able to use the caseID in the version query, a popup comes for me to enter what caseID is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SQLPlus you can try to declare a SQLPlus variable (this should also work with any GUI tool that is compatible with this kind of variable declaration such as SQL Developer, TOAD, ...):

```
variable caseID number;
BEGIN
   SELECT case_id INTO :caseID FROM cases WHERE user_id = 'test';
END;
/
select * from version where case_id = :caseID;
```

Another possibility that does not use special client syntax but only PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
caseID number;
v version%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT case_id INTO caseID FROM cases WHERE user_id = 'test';
   SELECT * INTO v FROM version WHERE case_id = caseID;
END;
/
```

But in this case you have to code everything in PL/SQL and make sure to process output of SELECT statements.

Comment: The tool i'm using is DBeaver and I tried your answer. It gave me an invalid SQL statement

Comment: I've updated by answer with a full PL/SQL solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `@set` command in `DBeaver` to define and assign it at once and use it in the session:

```
@set userId='test'
@set caseId=(SELECT case_id FROM cases WHERE user_id = :userId)
SELECT * FROM version where case_id = :caseId
```